# Change of basis for the Frobenius normal form

Tags: abstract-algebra, change-of-basis

$M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over a field $k$. I try to find a basis with respect to which $M$ is block diagonal with blocks of the form:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0      &    0   & \cdots  & 0       &  a_0    \\
    1      &   0    & \ddots  & 0       & a_1     \\
    0      & \ddots &  \ddots &  \ddots & \vdots  \\
    0      & 0      & \ddots  & 0       & a_{d-2} \\
    0      & 0      & \cdots  & 1       & a_{d-1} \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

(This is the Frobenius normal form, right?)
I have been given the following hint:
*M acts naturally on some n-dimensional k-vector space $V$. Consider $V$ as a $k[x]$-module via $f.v$ = $f(M)(v)$.*

I have no idea where to start, and in particulary I don't see how to use the hint.

Comment: Do you know about the structure of modules over principal rings ?

Comment: In any case you might want to start with the case where there is a vector $v$ such that the $M^i(v)$ generate $V$ (so $V$ is $M$-cyclic).